# IOS: availability date for app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I uploaded an app on itunesConnect and i set availability date on 20/02/2012. Yesterday I received an email that say that my app is in "Processing for appStore"; today I have entered in itunesconnect and I have seen that my app is ready for sale; but in the version summary app availability date is 20/02/2012. What does it mean? Can I be sure that my app begin the sale on 20/02/2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relax, the availability date controls when others can download it. But once the approval process is finished it'll be ready for sale, which reserves the page URL for it and allows you to send out redemption codes should you want others to download it early for testing etc.